# How to get date from week number & day number and year?

Tags: php, function, date, datetime, strtotime

I'm trying to get the date from the week number, day number and year.

For eg:

```
week number = 52   
day number = 4 (of week 52)  
year = 2013
```

In this case, the date should be `26-12-2013`.

How can I do it using PHP? I've already tried with `strtotime()`, but I'm confused about the formats. Can someone help?

Comment: What you tried so far?

Comment: I tried with strtotime function , but i am confused with the format..
just we neet time and easy to get date

Comment: @Vineet: open [this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), and take a look at the right,where is says `Date with week number:  2013-W52-3`. Have you tried `strtotime()` with parameter like that? `2013-W52-4`

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make use of [**`setISODate()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.setisodate.php)

```
<?php
$gendate = new DateTime();
$gendate->setISODate(2013,52,4); //year , week num , day
echo $gendate->format('d-m-Y'); //"prints"  26-12-2013
```

Comment: What a bout clashes at the end of the year? Is it safe?

Answer (score 5):

Try this code.

```
 <?php

    function change_date($week_num, $day) {
      $timestamp    = strtotime(date('Y') . '-W' . $week_num . '-' . $day);
      return $timestamp;
    }
   $timestamp = change_date(52, 4);
    echo date('d-m-Y', $timestamp);
?>
```

Comment: You should also give year as parameter. And watch out for week numbers bellow 10, because week number must always have 2 integers.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the `strtotime` function. In your example, you can write:

```
date("Y-m-d", strtotime("Y2013W52-4")) // outputs: 2013-12-26
```

The strtotime will give you a timestamp that you can use in combination withe the date function.